# Could Not Send Query :Broken Pipe nested Exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException

Tags: sql, spring, jboss, mariadb, spring-batch

I am running an insert query in spring batch using JdbcBatchItemWriter and my query something like this ::

```
<bean id="dumpFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[
    INSERT INTO feed (a, b, c, d .....  e)
                         VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,?,?,?)
                         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                          a = IF(last_change_tim < ?, ?, a),
                          b = IF(last_change_tim < ?, ?, b),
                          c = IF(last_change_tim < ?, ?, c),
                          d = IF(last_change_tim < ?, ?, d),
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                          e = IF(last_change_tim < ?, ?, e),




<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/datasources/mariaDB" pool-name="mariaDB" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:mariadb:databse</connection-url>
<driver-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
<connection-property name="cachePrepStmts">
false
</connection-property>
<driver>maria</driver>
<pool>
<min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
</pool>
<security>
<user-name>user</user-name>
<●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●</password>
</security>
<validation>
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
<background-validation>false</background-validation>
<stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
</validation>
<timeout>
<set-tx-query-timeout>true</set-tx-query-timeout>
<blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
<idle-timeout-minutes>10</idle-timeout-minutes>
<query-timeout>300</query-timeout>
<use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
<allocation-retry>3</allocation-retry>
<allocation-retry-wait-millis>300</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
</timeout>
<statement>
<share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
</statement>
</datasource>
```

I kept the chunk size to 1000. When i run batch for 100k records, broken pipe error occurs sometimes at 1k, sometimes at  10k and so on. So my question is what could be the reason for this issue? And any solution for this?

Comment: there are buffers to smal. pls post your db server-config

Comment: @BerndBuffen i have edited and re posted.

Comment: sorry - i mean the server config file under /etc/mysql/my.cnf or post the output from **SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;**

Comment: @BerndBuffen I am using mariadb as database. Sharing datasource present in the standalone file in jboss server

Comment: see this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-memory-allocation/ . iam nearly sure that the net_buffer_length is to small